# Is the sum of two stable matrices also stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, eigenvalues

Let $A$ and $B$ be two arbitrary real matrices of the same dimension. If the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are all in the left half of the complex plane, can we estimate the the location of the eigenvalues of matrix $A+B$?

Assume that there is no common $P$, such that $PA+A'P \prec 0$ and $PB+B'P \prec 0$.

From some simple experiments, I found that the eigenvalues of $A+B$ are still on the left half of the complex plane. But I can not prove it. Is there any proved result I can relate to?

Comment: $<0$ means negative definite. Existence of $P>0$ severs a sufficient condition for $A+B$ to be stable. Now let's assume that existence of such $P$ is unknown.

Comment: If $\rm A, B$ commute, i.e., if $\rm A B = B A$, then $\rm A + B$ is also stable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the example
$$ A = \pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 1 & 0\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr} $$
$A$ and $B$ have eigenvalues $0$, but $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A+B$.

I'm not sure in what sense you mean $< 0$ (element-wise?  negative definite?).  But for any $P$, $(P A + A' P)_{1,1} = 0$ and $(P B + B' P)_{2,2} = 0$, so there is no such $P$ in either sense.

EDIT: To make $A$ and $B$ have **strictly** negative eigenvalues, subtract some small $\epsilon$ from their diagonal elements.  $A+B$ will still have an eigenvalue $1-2\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned that $<0$ means negative definite. The real parts of eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are strictly negative. Existence of such $P$ only serves as a sufficient condition for $A+B$ to be stable. Now just assume such the existence of such $P$ is unknown.

Comment: This counter example is good. Thank you!